# Get absolute path of a key from nested dictionary in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary object in python, I will give two parameters to a method which is some key name key and the json object, i want to receive an output that will have the absolute path of the key.

Example json object and the key name is "year"

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "cars": {
    "car1": {
      "name": "CD300",
      "make": {
        "company": "Benz",
        "year": "2019"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my function will be something like below

```
def get_abs_path(json, key):
    print(res)
```

expected output
res = cars.car1.make.company

Comment: you want abs path of the key ?

Comment: in that case get_abs_path(json, 'year') will return cars.car1.make.year right ? @Ashwin S

Comment: @AsifMohammed yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def is_valid(json, key):
    if not isinstance(json, dict):
        return None
    if key in json.keys():
        return key
    ans = None
    for json_key in json.keys():
        r = is_valid(json[json_key], key)
        if r is None:
            continue
        else :
            ans = "{}.{}".format(json_key, r)
    return ans

a = {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "cars": {
        "car1": {
            "name": "CD300",
            "make": {
                "company": "Benz",
                "year": "2019"
            }
        }
    }
}
def get_abs_path(json, key):
    path = is_valid(json, key)
    print(path)

get_abs_path(a, 'company')
```